# Whether to use a digital switch IC or SMD transistors

Tags: transistors, digital-logic

I am creating a PCB, and have a few pins on a microcontroller that I would like to pull high when I want to go into programming mode, but leave them disconnected otherwise.

I have a connector which will be connected when programming. I am using one of the pins going to the connector to detect if the connector is connected and thus if the microcontroller should be in programming mode,

I currently am using a set of SMD transistors, but in searching for a transistor to use I discovered Digital Switches.

How should I decide if I should use a digital switch instead of a transistor?

I have attached my schematic below. My microcontroller is an ESP-12F, and I am using KiCad as my PCB design software.

[image]

Comment: Last time I had mandatory pull up resistors for programming I added them to the programmer. Zero BOM cost, zero surface area and no need for interesting solutions like this

Comment: Fair enough. Besides that, does it still seem like this would work as it is?

Comment: Worked great, though it wasn’t an ESP chip. Your results may vary. Test it out.

Comment: It's unclear what the circuit should even do. The description that a connector should bridge 3V3 to ground seems like it would just short circuit the power supply. How do you really want to control the pins?

Comment: Q1-3 don't seem to be the right configuration to do anything sensible. Draw your schematic conventionally, +ve at top, then it's easier to see what's going on. Which pins in your cable are bridged? Draw a truth table of the desired connections/states for esp_en, gpio0, gpio15, esp_rst with, and without, the programming connector attached.

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified that it bridges the 3V3 and GND pins on the connector, which then causes the 4 transistors to close, connecting EN, GPIO0, and RST to 3V3, and GPIO15 to GND